# Simulate many client socket on a single host

Tags: java, sockets, chat, distributed-computing

This is how the application appears: [UI Chat socket java application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8R5o.jpg)

Hi guys!
I wrote this FXML java application, it's a simple chat. I want to test the concurrency of many client simulating messages sending of many client. In other words, I want to write a code that run many istances of the Client class (*extends Application*) and one of the Server. At this point, clients must send messages automatically and simultaneously to test the concurrency.
I know I can't excute many Clients programms on the same JVM, so there's another way. 
this is the running class of client:

```
public class ClientSide extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    Region root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLClient.fxml"));
    Undecorator undecorator = new Undecorator(stage,root);
    undecorator.getStylesheets().add("skin/undecorator.css");
    Scene scene = new Scene(undecorator);

    // Transparent scene and stage
    scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);

    // Set minimum size
    stage.setMinWidth(500);
    stage.setMinHeight(400);

    stage.setTitle("ChatProject - Client console");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    stage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

I did not find anything about that.
Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You need to write a new client without a UI, that connects to the API on the server to send messages. Then you run that client many times in the same VM. If your server API is based on HTTP or another well-known protocol, you may be able to create this client as a JMeter script and then you can configure that to run concurrently many times.

Comment: No way preserving the UI? Something like loading many ui client in a single stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you use websocets or http protocols you can try testing with tsung.